# Receiving data that was sent to serial port before first read

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I am using ASIO to read/write to a device through a serial port. When I start my program, I first need to ensure that the device is properly configured. This is done by a series of writes in an `initialize_device()` function. The device sends back some data which is of no interest after these calls.

When `initialize_device()` is done, I call my `start_receive()` function which in turns calls an `asio::async_read_until()`, and my handler again calls `start_receive()`

The problem, however, is that the irrelevant data that was sent to me during `initialize_device()` is "received" by my handler, even though this was data that was received before my first read. This was unexpected for me.

I am thus wondering if there's a correct way to "flush" the internal buffer that the asio::serial_port uses after `initialize_device()` is completed? I really ain't interested in any data that was received before I explicitly start reading the port.

Answer (score 2):

The device will have a documented protocol.

You will have to be able to tell what is sent in response to your initializing commands.

Just use `async_read_until` to get this information into a dummy buffer (`boost::asio::null_buffer`?) before you start reading the "real" data.

Comment: I could not get null_buffer to work with async_read_until. I have now decided to handle the returned initialization data, though I could still see cases where one wouldn't want to handle any data received prior to the first receive. Guess one could use a simple bool to indicate if data should be processed by the handler or not.

Comment: Indeed. You simply cannot decide "not to receive" data that the device has decided to send. You'll have to explicitly ignore/discard it